# show that the error $ \ (f-P_n) \ $ is orthogonal to the space of all polynomial of $ \mathcal{P}_n \ $

Tags: linear-algebra

The solution $ \ P_n(x) $ to the least square approximation of $ \ f \ $ by a polynomial of degree at most  $ \ n \ $ is given explicitly in terms of orthogonal polynomials $ \ \psi_0(x) , \ \psi_1(x) , ............., \psi_n(x) \ $ where $ \ \psi_j(x) \ $ is polynomial of degree $ \ j \ $

$P_n(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{n} a_i \psi_i(x) \ $ and  $ \ \large a_i=\frac{\left\langle f,\psi_i \right\rangle }{\left\langle \psi_i , \psi_i \right\rangle} $

Then **show that** the error $ \ (f-P_n) \ $ is **orthogonal** to the space of all polynomial of $ \mathcal{P}_n \ $ of degree at most $ \ n \ $.

**That is**, $ \ \left\langle f-P_n , p \right\rangle =0 \ \  $ for some polynomial $ \ \large p \in \mathcal{P}_n \ $

**How to use Geometry and vector concept to analyze the above fact ?**

**Answer:**

Now the polynomial  $ \ p \in \mathcal{P}_n \ $  should be of the form

$ p=\sum_{i=0}^{n} c_i \psi_i(x) \ $ ,

Now,

$ \left\langle f-P_n, p \right\rangle \\ = \left\langle f-\sum_{i=0}^{n} a_i \psi_i(x), \sum_{i=0}^{n} c_i \psi_i(x) \right\rangle \\ = \left\langle f, \sum_{i=0}^{n} c_i \psi_i(x) \right\rangle -\left\langle \sum_{i=0}^{n} a_i \psi_i(x) , \sum_{i=0}^{n} c_i \psi_i(x) \right\rangle \\ = \sum_{i=0}^{n} c_i a_i \left\langle \psi_i , \psi_i \right\rangle - \sum_{i=0}^{n} c_i a_i \left\langle \psi_i, \psi_i \right\rangle=0 $

(By definition of $ a_i \ $ and noting the fact that $ \ \left\langle \psi_i, \psi_j \right\rangle =0 \ $ if $ \ i \neq j \ $ )

Thus $ (f-P_n \ $ is orthogonal to the space $ \ \mathcal{P}_n \ $

**But how to analyze in geometrical aspect by drawing vector projection.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that for any (closed) subspace $V \subset L^2(\mathbb{R})$, there is an orthogonal projection onto $V$, $\pi_V$. So, $\pi_V(f) = P_n$. Moreover, $\pi_V(f)$ is also the element of $V$ that minimizes $L_2$ distance (square distance) to $f$.

When you write $f = P_n + (f- P_n)$, you are writing $f$ as a sum of two orthogonal vectors. You know that $(f - P_n)$ is orthogonal to $V$, because $\pi_V(f - P_n) = \pi_V(f) - \pi_V(P_n) = P_n - P_n = 0$.

See here for more details on these concepts: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)

or [Orthogonal projection on the Hilbert space .](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/275391/orthogonal-projection-on-the-hilbert-space)