# Alternative ways to show that a set of elements span a space?

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces, wavelets

Could we rigorously prove the following?

> In a Hilbert Space $\mathcal{H}$, if $f, \phi_j \in \mathcal{H}$ for all $j \in J$, and $$\left<f, \phi_j\right> = 0 \text{  for all } j \in J \implies f = 0$$
> then $\{\phi_j\}_{j \in J}$ spans $\mathcal{H}$.

This intuitively makes sense, but do we have formal proof?

P.S. This is from *Ten Lectures on Wavelets Chapter 3*, in the proof of proposition 3.2.1.

Comment: HINT: The assumption implies that the space spanned by $(\phi_j)_j$ has trivial orthogonal complement.

Comment: 2.HINT: Use the orthogonal decomposition theorem which can be found in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/275391/orthogonal-projection-on-the-hilbert-space) or [here (3.6)](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Functional_Analysis/Hilbert_spaces).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $V := \displaystyle\bigoplus_{j \in J} \operatorname{span}\lbrace \phi_j \rbrace$. Your assumption implies $V^\perp = \lbrace 0 \rbrace$. Let $P: \mathcal{H} \rightarrow V$ be the linear projection onto $V$, i.e.
$$
(f - Pf, v) = 0 \quad \forall v \in V \quad \iff Pf = \operatorname*{argmin}_{v \in V} \lVert f - v \rVert.
$$
According to the projection theorem for Hilbert Spaces, this is well defined and the equivalence stated above holds. Note that $f$ in $\ker(P)$ iff $(f, v) = 0$ for all $v \in V$. So $\ker(P) = \lbrace 0 \rbrace$ according to our assumption.
Furtheremore, since $Pf \in V$, we have $PPf = Pf$ according to the $\operatorname{argmin}$ definition of the projection.
Note that for any $x \in \mathcal{H}$:
$$
x = \underbrace{(x - Px)}_{\in \ker(P) \implies 0} + \underbrace{Px}_{\in V}
$$
Therefore
$$
\mathcal{H} = \ker(P) \oplus V = \lbrace 0 \rbrace \oplus V = V
$$
and we are done.

$x - Px \in \ker(P)$ holds because of
$$
P(x-Px) = Px - PPx = Px - Px = 0.
$$